# Go does not support operator overloading, but how do I explain the time package

Tags: go, operator-overloading

I have been doing the Go tour for a while now and I just noticed this line of code:-

```golang
today := time.Now().Weekday()
    switch time.Saturday {
    case today + 0:
        fmt.Println("Today.")
    case today + 1:
        fmt.Println("Tomorrow.")
    case today + 2:
        fmt.Println("In two days.")
    default:
        fmt.Println("Too far away.")
    }
```

If Go does not support operator overloading how is that I can use the '+' operator to increment the day?

Comment: Did you look at what [`Weekday`](https://pkg.go.dev/time?tab=doc#Weekday), and the individual days of the week actually are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time.Now().Weekday()` returns a value of type `time.Weekday`, which is an `int`. `today+1` works, because 1 is an untyped constant, and its type is determined based on context. In this context, both `today` and `1` are of type `time.Weekday`.

Also note that because of the way it is defined, time.Saturday is 6, 
so `time.Saturday == today+2` works, but `time.Saturday+2` is not going to match any valid weekday.

Comment: But (time.Saturday) % 7 would.

Comment: So the value of `time.Now().Weekday()` isn't typesafe?! I thought Go was all about not having implicit conversions.

Comment: @Ben, It is typesafe. There are no implicit conversions. The result of time.Saturday%7 is still of type Weekday. The operations that are valid for the underlying type are still valid for the derived type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your problem, but I think you can pay attention to the `time` package. It's powerful.

There are many time types in go, such as `time.weekday`, `time.duration`, and `time.month`. They support the `+` operator, because their underlying type is numeric, but `time.Time` is not supported. Its underlying type is structure. We can use the method of `time.Time` for operation, such as `Time.add`, `Time.sub`, `Time.adddate`, `Time.after`, `Time.before`, `Time.equa` You can use `Time.unix` or `Time.unixnano` to get the Time stamp of numerical type for operation.

As an example, I implemented two methods to calculate the time from a certain time to the next week and the deviation from the current time.

```golang
import (
    "time"
)

func NextWeekdayTime(now time.Time, weekday time.Weekday) time.Time {
    return now.AddDate(0, 0, NextWeekdayNum(now, weekday))
}

func NextWeekdayNum(now time.Time, weekday time.Weekday) int {
    diff := (weekday - now.Weekday()) + 7
    if diff >= 7 {
        diff -= 7
    }

    return int(diff)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains it all, I should've known that the underlying primitive type was an int.